# Why I cannot bundle two sql commands with a ''with" statement in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Does with statement work with multiple sql commands?
I have to delete entries in 2 tables. My sql is like this:

```
with tbd as (
 SELECT (row_value ->> 'id')::INTEGER 
 FROM public.row_history 
 where record_table = 'survey_storage' 
 and row_value ->> 'status' = 'Never Surveyed' 
 except
  (SELECT (row_value ->> 'id')::INTEGER 
   FROM public.row_history 
   where record_table = 'survey_storage' 
   and row_value ->> 'status' = 'Ready to Launch') 
  limit 1)
delete from row_history where (row_value ->> 'id')::INTEGER = ANY(ARRAY(select * from tbd)) 
delete from survey_storage where id = ANY(ARRAY(select * from tbd))
```

This is not working.Out of 2 delete statement if you comment out one, then the other one works. But together they do not even compile.Definitely I can write 2 sql  scripts each with 1 delete - but I want to do this in one go.
I get this error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "delete"
                   Position: 410
                   ERROR: syntax error at or near "delete"
                   Position: 410
                   ERROR: syntax error at or near "delete"
                   Position: 410
```

Comment: @The Impaler, Thanks for answering.Tried to create a stored procedure for exactly same content. It did not like ''with''. So I will go with 2 scripts or 2 stored procedures.

Comment: you can use multiple ```cte```s and write each ```delete ``` statements inside.

Comment: @abdusoli, gr8. It works.I wrapped first delete inside 2nd cte, and left second delete as it is.It worked.If you convert your comment to answer I will accept. Thanks.

Comment: @Abdusoli I stand corrected. This seems to be an extension of PostgreSQL (that always surprises me). I tried also with Oracle, DB2, MySQL, MariaDB, and SQL Server to no avail. Anyway, it's good to know it can be done in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like below:

```
with tbd as (
 SELECT (row_value ->> 'id')::INTEGER 
 FROM public.row_history 
 where record_table = 'survey_storage' 
 and row_value ->> 'status' = 'Never Surveyed' 
 except
  (SELECT (row_value ->> 'id')::INTEGER 
   FROM public.row_history 
   where record_table = 'survey_storage' 
   and row_value ->> 'status' = 'Ready to Launch') 
  limit 1)
), cte2 as (
  delete from row_history 
     where (row_value ->> 'id')::INTEGER 
                        = ANY(ARRAY(select * from tbd))
)
delete from survey_storage
     where id = ANY(ARRAY(select * from tbd));
```